# View value of variables in some kind of output in IBM RPG

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I am trying to learn IBM RPG and rewrite a program for my employer. I need a way to see whether my variables are getting assigned to the values i expect them too but i dont know how to output something to my screen to just display the values. Is there a way to send a break message containing the variables in the RPG program, not the CL program?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the display (DSPLY) op-code
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzasd/sc092508935.htm%23zzdsply

```
dsply 'Hello World';
dsply 'value is:' + %char(myNumber);
dsply myString;

//the above don't pause, you'll see the message pop up and go away,  
// but it will be in the joblog.  If you want to wait:
dsply myString '*EXT' myResponse;
```

Comment: Buck makes a good point...depending on how much / often you're checking, using a debugger may be a better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

There are several debuggers available to you which can not only show the contents of variables, but alter them as well.  I prefer to use [RDi](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=49773f8f-a20d-4816-86f2-44a2d862dbc1) as my editing environment, and the graphical debugger that comes with it is superb.

There are several green screen debuggers, documented [here](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Debugging_ILE_program_in_batch) at the Midrange wiki.  The IBM i command STRDBG is used for ILE programs (and OPM if they're compiled with OPTION(*SRCDBG)) and the STRISDB command is often used with older, OPM programs.

Comment: If RDi (nor WDSC) isn't available, then a version of the [System i5 (graphical) Debugger](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzamq/rzamqmain.htm?lang=en) can be used through System i Navigator and 'Run SQL scripts'. And if Navigator isn't available, the System i5 Debugger can be downloaded from the server and installed as a stand-alone on a PC. Both Navigator and the System i5 Debugger are free to use.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion of a Debugger is the best one.  I work in RPG400(pre ILE). For that, i can list the steps I use. Hopefully this might be a help if you arent doing ILE Or RPG4. I have an RPG program, ABRKR being called by ABROADC (the CL).
Im going to debug ABRKR and NOT step thru the CL, I know that works. 
Disclaimer: Green screen programming coming.

- On the command line, type   STRISDB   & press F4

[image]

- Type in the name of the program, library .....(yatta yatta)

  [image]
- Press ENTER to finish it up....
  Im calling the ABROADC. Notice the Invoke Program

[image]

- Press ENTER to start the ball rolling

[image]

- Once in the program, press F5 to Start stepping thru the program

  [image]
- you can step thru your code 1 line at a time by pressing F5
- to check a variable value, position the cursor on the variable & press F11

[image]

[image]

- Press ENTER or F12 to back out of the detail screen.

  - Press F3 to exit the debugger... OR ...
  - Position the cursor to any line you want, press F13 (shift F1) to jump to that line of code.  If you found what you wanted & want the program to run to its end, just jump to the *INLR or LR indicator where you turn it on & press ENTER. The job will run to completion.

My apologies to everyone who hates fixed format, and old tech. I am making an effort to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Charles almost get it.

With dsply just add a blank after de value and will pop up the message and will stay there until you hit enter!

```
dsply 'Hello World' ' ';
dsply 'value is:' + %char(myNumber) ' ';
dsply myString ' ';
```